# How to verbally express this mathematical formula?

Tags: mathematics

I am going to deliver a tutorial. However, I am not sure how to express some formulae verbally in a correct way. Could you please help me?

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to express it verbally? The whole point of mathematical notation is that it is clear, concise and unambiguous. If you really need to express it verbally, you would probably get a more reliable answer on Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about mathematics

Comment: @JavaLatte I wonder whether the OP was asking how to read it aloud?

Comment: @mdewey I understand that that's what the OP was asking. I am asking why? Very few people could parse an equation as complex as this, even if somebody were to read it out without making any mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking how to read the formula alound then this source

https://par.cse.nsysu.edu.tw/link/Mathe-pronun.pdf

may help you. It does come from a French institution but I believe it describes usage in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

I agree this is not the right place, but I can help you out with a few of the terms

1. 2*br -> "two b r(or b subscript r)" or "two times b r"\
2. log a(b) would be -> "log of b to the base a"\
3. b/M would be -> "b over M"

As suggested by @JavaLatte, it would not be ideal to read out such a large equation.

Answer (score 0):

The equation contains multiple nested functions, which makes it difficult. But:

- *a<sub>b</sub>* is pronounced "*a*-sub-*b*"
- ⌊*a*⌋ is pronounced "floor *a*" or "the floor of *a*"
- ⌈*a*⌉ is pronounced "ceil *a*" or "the ceiling of *a*"
- log<sub>*b*</sub>(*a*) is pronounced "log base-*b* of *a*"
- *a*/*b* is pronounced "*a* over *b*"

so I would pronounce the whole thing like this:

Two bee-sub-arr, plus
two bee-sub-arr times the ceiling of log base floor-em-over-beebee minus one of bee-sub-arr over em, minus
bee-sub-arr

equals

bee-sub-arr, times
two times the ceiling of log base-floor-em-over-beebee minus one of bee-sub-arr over emm, plus one

---

You can see how confusing and ambiguous that is, because there are many places in the formula where there are parentheses or other groupings that are not spoken aloud. But if the formula is displayed on the screen as you say it that won't matter.

Comment: Thank you. I will display the formula on the screen of course. Otherwise, people could not understand what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Don't.

You label the equation with a number (eg 6) and then say "Equation 6"

You would never try to read this out loud.  There would be no point. Nobody could understand you.   Nobody can keep this whole complex expression in their head.  The point of writing things down is because they can't be expressed clearly in speech.

Simple expressions  2+2 "two plus two" or "log₂(3π/2) "log base two of three pi by two" can be expressed in words.  Your expression is far far too complex.  So don't read it aloud.  Let your students see the expression on the slides, or the handouts.

Comment: Yeah, You are right. It is not suitable to read it aloud. I would say let's recall the formula to calculate XXXX, which is shown here.